# Method SerialInputStream.read(byte[] bytes) returns 0 even though data is available for reading

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication, jssc, com-port

I encountered a problem from library nrjavaserial when we comunicate with com-port for emulating NMEA device: when calling the RXTXPort#SerialInputStream.read(byte[] bytes) method, the result is 0. The bytes parameter is never empty, bytes are read. Presumably the problem can also be caused by the int a = nativeavailable();(RXTXPort#1467) method, which returns 0, so Minimum = 1, with the consequence that in the readArray(b, off, Minimum)(RXTXPort#1492) method the result is 0. Here is the code from the library itself where the problem occurs:
`public synchronized int read( byte b[], int off, int len )
throws IOException
{
.....
int Minimum = len;

```
        if( threshold==0 )
        {
        /*
         * If threshold is disabled, read should return as soon
         * as data are available (up to the amount of available
         * bytes in order to avoid blocking)
         * Read may return earlier depending on the receive time
         * out.
         */
            int a = nativeavailable(); // i think main problem is here a = 0
            if( a == 0 )
                Minimum = 1;
            else
                Minimum = Math.min( Minimum, a );
        }
....
        IOLockedMutex.readLock().lock();
        try
        {
            waitForTheNativeCodeSilly();
            result = readArray( b, off, Minimum);//result = 0
            if (debug_read_results)
                z.reportln( "RXTXPort:SerialInputStream:read(" + b.length + " " + off + " " + len + ") returned " + result + " bytes" /*+ new String(b) */);
            return( result );
        }`
```

**It is important** to note that the problem is not static, i.e. periodic, sometimes it can read normally, and sometimes the problem pops up and it can hang for a few minutes.

My code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  
  inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
  
  while (!isInterrupted())
  {
  
    // problem is here, it returns 0 sometimes ->
     int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer); ////RXTXPort#SerialInputStream.read(byte[] bytes)
    
    if (bytesRead == -1)
      break;
    
   ..........
    
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);`
```

What is the problem and is it definitely related to my code?

Comment: Get rid of the available() stuff. It doesn’t help. `read()` already behaves as described in the comment.

Comment: Your question needs work. The text isn't clear what you're asking, the code samples aren't clear what you're trying to do. Java code has types, almost none of which are present in your code sample. You tagged JSSC but you're using RXTX.